# Почему контроллер не отображает страницу в java Spring

Tags: java, spring

Я новичок в Spring и пытаюсь разобраться в данном фреймворке. Смотрю курс по java Spring и тут у меня возникла ошибка, что контроллер не отображает страницу, а выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перепробовал всё возможное, для решения этой задачи, но так и не решилось.

1. Использую TomCat 9.
2. Пересоздавал проект
3. Менял версии зависимости в pom.xml связанные с thymeleaf и менял одну из зависимостей на jakarta
4. Менял директории html файлов.
   Но при этом, когда я создал spring проект, там был изначальный файл (index.jsp) и он запускается автоматически без каких либо проблем. Помогите решить данную проблему
   Вот мой код:

HelloControler:

```
package ru.nikita.springcourse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/") // Создание ссылки
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello_world";
    }

}
```

MySpringMVC:

```
package ru.nikita.springcourse.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

SpringConfig:

```
package ru.nikita.springcourse.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.nikita.springcourse")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

hello_world.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>6.0.5</version>
         </dependency>



         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>6.0.5</version>
         </dependency>

          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
          </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring6 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Вот мой каталог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На чистом спринге уже мало кто подскажет) Нет желания сделать то же самое, только без головной боли, на Spring Boot?

Comment: @Максим Я уже решил проблему, спасибо. Обязательно перейду на спринг бут, но пока хочу пощупать спринг голый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуется поставить jdk 8 и tomcat 9 + spring 5 и вуаля всё работает